# How to update macOS version over SSH in Big Sur or higher?

Tags: macos, software-update, big-sur, ssh

Previously it was possible to update macOS and restart it to finish updating with:

```
sudo softwareupdate -iaR
```

But after updating to Big Sur this is no longer possible as running the above will not restart the computer. And restarting it manually will not bump the OS version.

What is the alternative "incantation" for those looking to update macOS over SSH?